# How to join lines in unformatted XML file through Python

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file like below:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C a="xyz" b="123" c="x1" flag="yes">   (it in proper formatted)
        </C>
        <C a="abc"                (it is not proper formatted)
        b="234" c="y1"
        flag="no">
    </B>
</A>
```

Is there any way in Python to make the unformatted line in proper format by using any library?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [BeautifulSoup parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '''<A>
    <B>
        <C a="xyz" b="123" c="x1" flag="yes">
        </C>
        <C a="abc"
        b="234" c="y1"
        flag="no">
    </B>
</A>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'xml')
>>> print(soup.prettify())
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A>
 <B>
  <C a="xyz" b="123" c="x1" flag="yes">
  </C>
  <C a="abc" b="234" c="y1" flag="no">
  </C>
 </B>
</A>
```